# Python2.7 mmap over two lines with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, mmap

Here is the contents of a txt file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec
egestas, enim et consectetuer ullamcorper, lectus ligula rutrum leo, a
elementum elit tortor eu quam. Duis tincidunt nisi ut ante. Nulla
facilisi. Sed tristique eros eu libero. Pellentesque vel arcu. Vivamus
purus orci, iaculis ac, suscipit sit amet, pulvinar eu,
lacus. Praesent placerat tortor sed nisl. Nunc blandit diam egestas
dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam viverra fringilla
leo. Nulla feugiat augue eleifend nulla. Vivamus mauris. Vivamus sed
mauris in nibh placerat egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris massa. Ut
eget velit auctor tortor blandit sollicitudin. Suspendisse imperdiet
justo.
```

and here is my code:

```
import mmap
import re
import contextlib

pattern = re.compile(r'[\S\s]{5,15}elementum......',
                     re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

with open('lorem.txt', 'r') as f:
    with contextlib.closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as m:
        for match in pattern.findall(m):
            print match.replace('\n', ' ')
```

Print fails to include anything from the prior line, even though I'm telling the program to delete newlines and I'm matching on everything.  How do I match the text on the prior line of my sample file?

[image: output]

Comment: This prints `" rutrum leo, a elementum elit "` (without quotes) on my system, exactly as I'd expect. What did you expect it to differently?

Comment: My output is " elementum elit ".  I'm running the program in shell, but I don't know why that would make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot suggests you're on Windows. With Windows line endings (`\r\n`) in `lorem.txt`, the output becomes `" rutrum leo, a\r elementum elit "`. The `\r` (carriage return) causes the cursor to hop back to the start of the line, so the first part is overwritten by the second:

```
$ python foo.py | od -tc
0000000   r   u   t   r   u   m       l   e   o   ,       a  \r       e
0000020   l   e   m   e   n   t   u   m       e   l   i   t      \n
0000037
```

To make the code platform-independent, use `os.linesep` instead of `'\n'`.

Another option is to use regular file reading functions instead of `mmap`, and to specify mode `'r'` (to assume platform-local line endings) or `'rU'` (to accept any of `\r`, `\r\n` and `\n`). This makes sure all line endings get converted to `\n` automatically.